# Norm of Operator : $Af(x)=f'(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

Problem

Let :
$$A~~:~C^{1}\left([0,1],||.||\right)\to~C\left([0,1],||.||_{\infty}\right)$$
$$Af(x)=f'(x)$$

Where : $||f||_{C^{1}}=||f||:=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$

I was prove that $A$ operator Linear and continue
$$|Af(x)|=|f'(x)|\leq~|f'(x)+|f(x)|\leq ||f||$$
$$\implies ||Af||_{\infty}\leq||f||$$
So : $||A||\leq1$

I need now prove that $||A||=1$
I tired to find a function  $f\in C^{1}$ such that $||f||=1$ and $||Af||=1$

I need idea for this

---

Thanks!

Comment: For $f_n(x)=x^n$ the ratio of the norms $\|A f_n\|$ and $\|f_n\|$ tends to $1.$

Answer (score 1):

In the codomain $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$, you have the usual supremum norm:
$$\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|,$$
where we can write "$\max$" instead of "$\sup$" since we're dealing with continuous functions on a compact interval.

In the domain $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$, you have the $\mathcal{C}^1$-norm:
$$\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}=\|f'\|_{\infty}+\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|+\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|+\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|.$$

Now, the operator norm in this case is:
$$\|A\|=\sup\frac{\|Af\|_{\infty}}{\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}}=\sup_{\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}\leqslant1}\|Af\|_{\infty},$$
and here "$\sup$" may be effectively necessary, not replaceable by "$\max$".

Indeed, if $\|Af\|_{\infty}=\|f'\|_{\infty}=1$, then $\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}=\|f'\|_{\infty}+\|f\|_{\infty}=1+\|f\|_{\infty}$, and that would be equal to $1$ iff $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$, which makes $f$ the identically zero function, which clearly doesn't work. So it's impossible to

> … find a function $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $\|Af\|=1$.

Instead, you need to come up with examples showing that the expression in the supremum (in either definition) can be arbitrarily close to $1$. For example, how about constructing a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ such that, even though $\frac{\|Af_n\|_{\infty}}{\|f_n\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}}<1$ for each of them, the limit of this ratio is $1$? Hint: power functions.

Comment: Thank you very much sir,,, I'm thankful, but sir whene $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}$ then $||f_{n}||=n+1≠1!!$ so $\frac{||Af_{n}||}{||f_{n}||}=\frac{n}{n+1}\to~1$ but is this method to find norm !! I was study find $f$ such that $||f||=1 \text{or}\leq 1$ so what about suite  here $||f_{n}||\geq 1$$ ??

Comment: First of all, the two definitions of the operator norm are equivalent. You can use functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ in the version of the definition that says $\|A\|=\sup\frac{\|Af\|_{\infty}}{\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}}$. So yes, it is a valid method. Alternatively, if you want functions of norm $1$, then you can take $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n+1}$ and use them in the version of the definition that says $\|A\|=\sup_{\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}\leqslant1}\|Af\|_{\infty}$.